# MVC DDD: Is it OK to use repositories together with services in the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, architecture, domain-driven-design

most of the time in the service code I would have something like this:

```
public SomeService : ISomeService
{
    ISomeRepository someRepository;
    public Do(int id)
    {
        someRepository.Do(id);
    }
}
```

**so it's kinda redundant**

so I started to use the repositories directly in the controller

is this ok ? is there some architecture that is doing like this ?

Comment: In practice, I don't have pass-through examples like this in my code. That said, one of the purposes of the repository is to provide the ability to mock it for unit testing purposes, so the additional layer of abstraction can be useful for that reason alone.

Comment: @Robert what's wrong with writing tests against controllers and mock repositories? apart from mocking controller dependencies - what else having services would change?

Comment: @Arnis: I guess what I meant was that the repository abstracts the database from your service code, so if you inject a different repository dependency, I guess you can call that a "mock."

Comment: @Robert no offence but that's one confusing comment. I think You are talking from 'do we need repositories?' context and me - 'do we need services?' context.

Comment: @Arnis: The repository is just a layer of abstraction. I'm not dogmatic about whether or not you need one.  If the additional layer of abstraction serves a purpose, use it. If it doesn't, don't use it just because someone says it is "correct" to do so.

Comment: @Robert I second You on that one. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You lose the ability to have business logic in between.

I disagree with this one.

If business logic is where it should be - in domain model, then calling repo in controller (or better - use model binder for that) to get aggregate root and call method on it seems perfectly fine to me.

Application services should be used when there's too much technical details involved what would mess up controllers.

---

> I've seen several people mention using model binders to call into a repo lately. Where is this crazy idea coming from?

I believe we are talking about 2 different things here. I suspect that Your 'model binder' means using model simultaneously as a view model too and binding changed values from UI directly right back to it (which is not a bad thing per se and in some cases I would go that road).

My 'model binder' is a class that implements '[IModelBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.imodelbinder.aspx)', that takes repository in constructor (which is injected and therefore - can be extended if we need caching with some basic composition) and uses it before action is called to retrieve aggregate root and replace `int id` or `Guid id` or `string slug` or `whatever` action argument with real domain object. Combining that with input view model argument lets us to write less code. Something like this:

```
public ActionResult ChangeCustomerAddress
 (Customer c, ChangeCustomerAddressInput inp){
  c.ChangeCustomerAddress(inp.NewAddress);
  return RedirectToAction("Details", new{inp.Id});
}
```

In my actual code it's a bit more complex cause it includes ModelState validation and some exception handling that might be thrown from inside of domain model (extracted into Controller extension method for reuse). But not much more. So far - longest controller action is ~10 lines long.

You can see working implementation (quite sophisticated and (for me) unnecessary complex) [here](http://codecampserver.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/4755c1386bff#src%2fUI%2fBinders%2fKeyedModelBinder.cs).

> Are you just doing CRUD apps with Linq To Sql or trying something with real domain logic?

As You can (hopefully) see, this kind of approach actually almost forces us to move towards [task based](http://herdingcode.com/?p=189) app instead of CRUD based one.

> By doing all data access in your service layer and using IOC you can gain lots of benefits of AOP like invisible caching, transaction management, and easy composition of components that I can't imagine you get with model binders.

...and having new abstraction layer that **invites** us to mix infrastructure with domain logic and lose isolation of domain model.

> Please enlighten me.

I'm not sure if I did. I don't think that I'm enlightened myself. :)

---

[Here](http://gist.github.com/557403) is my current model binder base class. [Here's](http://gist.github.com/557417) one of controller actions from my current project. And [here's](http://gist.github.com/557421) "lack" of business logic.

Comment: I've seen several people mention using model binders to call into a repo lately. Where is this crazy idea coming from? Are you just doing CRUD apps with Linq To Sql or trying something with real domain logic? By doing all data access in your service layer and using IOC you can gain lots of benefits of AOP like invisible caching, transaction management, and easy composition of components that I can't imagine you get with model binders. Please enlighten me.

Comment: c.ChangeCustomerAddress(inp.Address)
Does this method contain repository call to save the customer ? 
If so, how do you inject the repository inside customer ?

Comment: @mathieu it does not. I'm using NHibernate. that fella automatically updates dirty instances when session gets flushed. I like idea of encapsulated domain model. http://www.udidahan.com/2008/02/29/how-to-create-fully-encapsulated-domain-models/

Answer (score 1):

If you use repositories in your controllers, you are going straight from the Data Layer to the Presentation Layer.  You lose the ability to have business logic in between.

Now, if you say you will only use Services when you need business logic, and use Repositories everywhere else, your code becomes a nightmare.  The Presentation Layer is now calling both the Business and Data Layer, and you don't have a nice separation of concerns.

I would always go this route:  `Repositories -> Services -> UI`.  As soon as you don't think you need a business layer, the requirements change, and you will have to rewrite EVERYTHING.

Comment: I disagree, Business Logic isn't all or nothing. I'm not going to create a business logic layer just in-case I might need business logic down the road. It's pre-optimization. If you adhere to the SOLID principles, then a change in requirements can easily be dealt with. Calling Repositories from the controller is perfectly fine when it's a crud operation there is no business logic. If something changes and logic is needed, wrap the repository in a service and call the new service in the controller.

Comment: @Chuck from where do You guys think that calling repositories from controllers prohibits complex business logic?

Comment: @Chuck - Yeah, YAGNI.  But I have never seen CRUD operations without some sort of business logic.

Comment: @Arnis - You can have business logic when calling repositories from controllers, but I like to have a separate layer for the business logic.  Why not separate the business logic from the data logic and presentation logic?

Comment: You are right, it's good to separate those things in 99% cases. but I believe that thing You miss is so called 'rich domain model' (http://bit.ly/blT6NN).

Comment: Services in the DDD world should't have 'business logic'. That belongs to the AggregateRoot and its entities/value objects. Services simply orchestrate the operations around an AR.

Comment: Repository interfaces are part of the domain of course.

Answer (score 1):

**My own** rough practices for DDD/MVC:

- controllers are application-specific, hence they should only contain application-specific methods, and call Services methods.
- all public Service methods are usually atomic transactions or queries
- only Services instantiate & call Repositories
- my Domain defines an IContextFactory and an IContext (massive leaky abstraction as IContext members are IDBSet)
- each application has a sort-of [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/), which is mainly instantiating a Context Factory to pass to the Services (you could use DI container but not a big deal)

This forces me to keep my business code, and data-access out of my controllers.  I find it a good discipline, given how loose I am when I don't follow the above!

Comment: But I also appreciate the argument that some applications don't warrant calling a Service just to call some very similar method on a single entity.  Fair enough, but then you have to decide where your transaction begin and end.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the thing.

"Business Logic" should reside in your entities and value objects.

Repositories deal with AggregateRoots only. So, using your repositories directly in your Controllers kinda feels like you are treating that action as your "service". Also, since your AggregateRoot may only refer to other ARs by its ID, you may have to call one more than one repo. It really gets nasty very quickly.

If you are going to have services, make sure you expose POCOs and not the actual AggregateRoot and its members.

Your repo shouldn't have to do any operations other than creating, retrieving, updating and deleting stuff. You may have some customized retrieve based on specific conditions, but that's about it. Therefore, having a method in your repo that matches one in your service... code smell right there.

Your service are API oriented. Think about this... if you were to pack that service in a .dll for me to use, how would you create your methods in a way that is easy for me to know what your service can do? Service.Update(object) doesn't make much sense.

And I haven't even talked about CQRS... where things get even more interesting.

Your Web Api is just a CLIENT of your Service. Your Service can be used by another service, right? So, think about it. You most likely will need a Service to encapsulate operations on AggregateRoots, usually by creating them, or retrieving them from a repo, do something about it, then returning a result. Usually.

Makes sense?

Comment: makes sense, it's just that in a lot of applications for most entities (db tables) all we need is to do a simple crud, and end up with repo service and controller having a method with the exact same name

Answer (score -2):

Even with "rich domain model" you will still need a domain service for handling business logic which involves several entities. I have also never seen CRUD without some business logic, but in simple sample code. I'd always like to go Martin's route to keep my code straightforward.

Comment: Services shouldn't have 'business logic' in it. That's what Entities and Value Objects are for in DDD.